# We want to put 20 men into 8 rooms.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

a)How many ways we can do that in total? 
b)How many ways such that each room has $2$ men atleast?

My attempt: 
a) I am really not sure about it but what I did was, let $x_1,...,x_8$ be the rooms, so $x_1+...+x_8=20$, so ${28-1} \choose {20}$. I am not sure if it's the way to be solved, what I'm trying to understand if it's not said if the rooms or men are identical does it mean they're not and this should be in another way? would appreciate an explanation if someone knows. 
b) same way as (a) with $x_1,...,x_8 \ge 2$ and moving to $y_i = x_i -2$, from here same as (a). 

I am really not sure of my solutions, feel like I'm just solving randomly since the men can be distinct and this wouldn't work, I had a thought if this is linked to inclusion exclusion but I can't get how this is supposed to be solved. I would appreciate any help.

EDIT: I understand that the men are usually distinct, I would appreciate help on how to find the number of ways for (a) and (b) while rooms are indistinguishable.

Comment: If you only have $20$ men, it is not possible to have at least four men in each of the eight rooms.

Comment: Are the men distinct? Are the room distinct? (You seem to have an idea of what happens if the men are not distinct, but the rooms are)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks I messed up ill fix it, it's meant to be 2.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Yeah that's exactly why I decided to ask here, usually when talking about men in combinatorics, they mean they're distinct? I would love to see how it can be solved in other ways too, but I get that the question isn't really that clear?

Comment: If both men and rooms are distinct, you have $8^{20}$ choices for $(a)$.

Comment: @MathLover How many ways if the men are distinct and the rooms are indistinguishable?

Comment: I would usually consider men distinct unless otherwise stated. As far as rooms, the question should have clarified.

Comment: That would be $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{8} S2(20,i) \ $ where $S2$ is Stirling number of the second kind.